# How to make a div disappear by default, then re-appear using radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm currently writing a mock-website to work on my web development skills. It is a a mock-ice cream shop that doesn't exist in real life. Anyway - on the form to order ice cream, I want the two divs (deliveryDiv and pickupDiv) that have been created within the form to be hidden when the page loads, but nothing I have tried has worked so far.

Code

```js
function hideAAndB() {
  var pickupDiv = document.getElementById("pickupDiv");
  var deliveryDiv = document.getElementById("deliveryDiv");
  pickupDiv.style.display = "none";
  deliveryDiv.style.display = "none";
}

function hidePickup(x) { //Formally "hideA"
  if (x.checked) {
    document.getElementById("pickupDiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("deliveryDiv").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}

function hideDelivery(x) { //Formally "hideB"
  if (x.checked) {
    document.getElementById("deliveryDiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pickupDiv").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}


function init() {
  hideAAndB;
}

window.onload = init;
```

```css
#deliveryDiv,
#pickupDiv {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Order Page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="Order page for Sweet Life.">
  <meta name="keywords" content="study">
  <meta name="author" content="Anon">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="js/script1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="orderhtml">
    <!--Header-->
    <header>
      <h1 class="header" id="headerTop">Sweet Life</h1>
      <h2 class="header" id="headerBottom">Discover a world of ice cream...</h2>
    </header>
    <!--Navigation bar-->
    <div id="topnav">
      <nav class="nav">
        <a href="order.html">Order online</a>
        <a href="register.html">Register</a>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tagline">
      <h2>Order</h2>
    </div>
    <!--Form-->
    <form id="orderForm">
      <p>First, select either delivery or pickup:</p>
      <label for="delivery">Delivery</label>
      <input type="radio" id="delivery" name="delivery" onchange=hidePickup(this) value="Delivery"><br>
      <label for="pickup">Pickup</label>
      <input type="radio" id="pickup" name="pickup" onchange=hideDelivery(this) value="Pickup"><br>
      <div id="pickupDiv">
        <br/>A's text</div>
      <div id="deliveryDiv">
        <br/>B's text</div>
  </div>
  </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

:

I tried to set the "visibility" to "hidden" in the HTML, and tried to use CSS and JS here to (unsuccessfully) hide both divs. As you can see, I have attemoted to solve this on my own, but am getting a bit lost. The radio buttons do work, if you select one then one of the divs does appear. But they're visible when the page loads. HELP!

Comment: Hello, please write a [mcve]. :)

Comment: There's no need to use both `display` and `visibility`. Pick one or the other, depending on how you want the layout to be affected when the element is hidden.

Comment: `hideAAndB;` doesn't do anything. You need `()` to call the function: `hideAAndB();`

Comment: *"I want the two divs (deliveryDiv and pickupDiv) [...] to be hidden when the page loads, but nothing I have tried has worked [...] The radio buttons do work, if you select one then one of the divs does appear."* - Am I missing something, or is the code in the question demonstrating the exact opposite of this problem description?

Comment: Your functions need to set `display` to `block` to make the divs appear.

Comment: There's no need to call `hideAAndB` when the page loads, because the CSS already hides them by default.

Answer (score 0):

you are setting both display and visibility you need to address both of them.  Although it's a little odd that you are using both.  display:none will not take up any space in the DOM while visibility takes up the space but doesn't show the element.

```js
function hideAAndB() {
  var pickupDiv = document.getElementById("pickupDiv");
  var deliveryDiv = document.getElementById("deliveryDiv");
  pickupDiv.style.display = "none";
  deliveryDiv.style.display = "none";
}

function hidePickup(x) { //Formally "hideA"

  if (x.checked) {
    document.getElementById("pickupDiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pickupDiv").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("deliveryDiv").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("deliveryDiv").style.visibility = "visible";
    
  }
}

function hideDelivery(x) { //Formally "hideB"
  if (x.checked) 
  {
    document.getElementById("deliveryDiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pickupDiv").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}


function init() {
  hideAAndB;
}

window.onload = init;
```

```css
#deliveryDiv,
#pickupDiv {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Order Page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="Order page for Sweet Life.">
  <meta name="keywords" content="study">
  <meta name="author" content="Anon">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="js/script1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="orderhtml">
    <!--Header-->
    <header>
      <h1 class="header" id="headerTop">Sweet Life</h1>
      <h2 class="header" id="headerBottom">Discover a world of ice cream...</h2>
    </header>
    <!--Navigation bar-->
    <div id="topnav">
      <nav class="nav">
        <a href="order.html">Order online</a>
        <a href="register.html">Register</a>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tagline">
      <h2>Order</h2>
    </div>
    <!--Form-->
    <form id="orderForm">
      <p>First, select either delivery or pickup:</p>
      <label for="delivery">Delivery</label>
      <input type="radio" id="delivery" name="delivery" onchange=hidePickup(this) value="Delivery"><br>
      <label for="pickup">Pickup</label>
      <input type="radio" id="pickup" name="delivery" onchange=hideDelivery(this) value="Pickup"><br>
      <div id="pickupDiv">
        <br/>A's text</div>
      <div id="deliveryDiv">
        <br>B's text
  </div>
  </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, pay attention to the name attribute: it should be the same for both radios or you will not be able to switch between them.

Then you can reduce the code to a single function that hides the div with id passed as an argument.

In this example, we use the `showDiv()` function to get the div that matches the id passed by the argument and toggle the `.hidden` which is set by default to both divs. This code can be adapted if you have more options or to pick the selection from a different set of divs.

```js
const showDiv = (id) => {
  const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div')
  
  divs.forEach(div => {
    if(div.getAttribute('id') === id){
      div.classList.remove('hidden')
    } else {
      if(!div.classList.contains('hidden')){
        div.classList.add('hidden')
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```css
div.hidden{
  display: none
}
```

```html
<label>
<input type="radio"  name="choose_div" onchange="showDiv('a')"/> Div A
</label>

<label>
<input type="radio" name="choose_div" onchange="showDiv('b')"/> Div B
</label>

<div id="a" class="hidden">Div A visible / Div B hidden</div>
<div id="b" class="hidden">Div B visible / Div A hidden</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in CSS with the [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) `:checked`, with the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) `[value='something']` and the [subsequent-sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Subsequent-sibling_combinator) `~`.

If you use the CSS property display or visibility is up to you.

```css
div#deliveryDiv {
  visibility: hidden;
}

div#pickupDiv {
  visibility: hidden;
}

input[value='delivery']:checked~div#deliveryDiv {
  visibility: visible;
}

input[value='pickup']:checked~div#pickupDiv {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<form id="orderForm">
  <p>First, select either delivery or pickup:</p>
  <label for="delivery">Delivery</label>
  <input type="radio" id="delivery" name="option" value="delivery"><br>
  <label for="pickup">Pickup</label>
  <input type="radio" id="pickup" name="option" value="pickup"><br>
  <div id="pickupDiv">
    <br/>A's text</div>
  <div id="deliveryDiv">
    <br/>B's text</div>
</form>
```